# Is there any method that allows the image to be resized in the server without manual actions(Uploading or downloading)

Tags: php, image, crop

We have in our server 2000 plus images with 2GB size and each one having the size 10MB. 
Now i want to reduce the specified size of each image. I have the images names.

I was implemented my application with custom php.

Is there any script to reduce the size of each image  without manual actions(Downloading and uploading)

If I send images names in an array(All at once or we can send those with certain interval based on the limit) then the script need to recognise the image with the name in the particular path then the script need to resize the image with specified ratio.

Can any one please suggest me.  Thankyou

Comment: Maybe imageMagic is what you need to look at

Comment: the short answer is yes,  you can use `gd` http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php or the command line im `convert` http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$file_to_compress = "/images/image.jpg";

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_to_compress);  
    unlink($file_to_compress);
   imagejpeg($image,$file_to_compress,50);

?>
```

Comment: this just changes the quality of the image at hand, I generally wouldn't recommend this, resizing the image would get you better results.